# Adding Crosswalk for only Android < 5.0

Tags: cordova, crosswalk

For the time being, it looks like I'll need to be supporting Android 4.x in my Cordova app. *Most* of the app's features work well, but I'm relying on a couple libraries that don't render too well on older Android versions:

- [Featherlight Gallery](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight)
- [Hopscotch.js walkthrough help](https://github.com/linkedin/hopscotch)

(My suspicion is that the older Android browser doesn't *quite* deal with the different stacking contexts correctly -- the buttons on the gallery and walkthrough popovers don't respond to events; instead, the UI behind them does.)

At any rate, is there a way to use the Crosswalk Cordova plugin **just for Android 4.x versions**?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the android versions that the plugins support by setting it in the plugin's plugin.xml . The plugin's plugin.xml can be found in `yourRootFolder/plugins/crosswalkPluginFolder/plugin.xml` . You should be able to see something similar to

```
<engine name="cordova-android" version="&gt;=5.1.1 &lt;7" />
```

You can specify the min and max versions here.

Comment: this will not limit the Android version but the Cordova Android platform version.